# make ruby script in console keep accepting input until you're done

Tags: ruby

I want to make a ruby script that runs in the console that will accept input and prompt for more input after accepting the previous input.

I know how to all of that except have it prompt again after the previous input. The script just stops after on input.

Do I just run it in a while loop or is there a better way?

Comment: You *really* should show your effort by including an example of what you've tried. Otherwise, it looks like you're fishing for code without having done anything.

Comment: oh, good point. I wasn't doing that, but I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,, you can try as something like below using `while` [*keyword*](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/) :

```
puts "Give your inputs"

while (a = gets.chomp) != 'exit'
  puts a
end

# or use until as below
until (a = gets.chomp) =~ /(?:ex|qu)it/i
      puts a
end
```

While you will enter the string `'Exit'`/`'exit'`/`'Quit'`/`'quit'` from the command prompt, your while loop will be stopped, Otherwise you will be keep prompting for the next input.

Comment: thanks, that is essentially what I did except that I was assigning "a" outside of the loop and getting an infinite loop. Assigning "a" in the while avoids this because every time through the loop gets is being called again right?

Comment: @isea Yes.. exactly.. First is being assigned to `a`, then comparing happened with `'exit'`.

Comment: `until (a = gets.chomp) ~= /[Ee]xit|[Qq]uit/` reveals more intent, and supports `'Exit' 'exit' 'Quit' 'quit'`

Comment: It'd be cleaner to use [`/(?:ex|qu)it/i`](http://rubular.com/r/n6ar3Qmzyn) which is case-insensitive.

Comment: Can I make this call methods in my script?